# Paxata Installation Issue

Tags: apache-spark

We have a multi-node installation of Paxata. There are three nodes

Paxata Core Server -> Paxata Core, Mongo, Web Server
Paxata Pipeline Server -> Pipeline, spark master 
Paxata Spark Server -> Paxata spark worker node

In this set up none of our processing steps in the UI seem to complete. Everything waits indefinitely.

The pipeline server keeps on spitting out this error below:

```
2017-08-24 12:02:12.488 GMT+0800 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] TaskSetManager - Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6, SPARK01): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:313)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:311)
    at com.paxata.spark.cache.CacheManagerRemoteClientImpl.register(CacheManagerRemoteClient.scala:148)
    at com.paxata.spark.cache.CacheManagerOnNodeImpl$$anonfun$getIndexCache$1.apply(CacheManagerOnNode.scala:220)
    at com.paxata.spark.cache.CacheManagerOnNodeImpl$$anonfun$getIndexCache$1.apply(CacheManagerOnNode.scala:219)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at com.paxata.spark.cache.CacheManagerOnNodeImpl.getIndexCache(CacheManagerOnNode.scala:219)
    at com.paxata.spark.PaxBootstrap$.init(PaxBootstrap.scala:13)
    at org.apache.spark.ExecutorActor$$anonfun$4.apply(SimpleSparkContext.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.ExecutorActor$$anonfun$4.apply(SimpleSparkContext.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Paxata pipeline server assumes one spark worker instance for each node of Paxata Spark Server. In our set up we had more than one spark worker running on the Paxata Spark Server. Once we changed the configurations to reduce the number of spark nodes to one the error went away.

Needed to change the following

```
$ cd /usr/local/paxata/spark/conf/
$ vi spark-env.sh
```

and then assigned all usable memory and cores of the node to the only worker node

```
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=10g
SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1
```